# What is the most natural way to make a relation into an equivalence relation?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, adjoint-functors, forgetful-functors

Let $S$ be a set and $R \subseteq S\times S$ be a binary relation on $S$ which is reflexive and symmetric.

**Method #1:** Say $x\sim y$ iff there exists some $s_0,\ldots, s_n\in S$ such that $s_0 = x$, and $s_n = y$, and $s_iRs_{i+1}$ for all $i$.

**Method #2:** Say $x\sim y$ iff $xRy$ and for all $z\in S$ such that $yRz$ we have $xRz$.

Both methods produce a, potentially different, equivalence relation. Let $\textsf{RSRel}$ be the category whose objects are sets equipped with a reflexive and symmetric relation, and morphisms are relation-preserving functions. Similarly one can define $\textsf{Equiv}$ to be the category of sets equipped with equivalence relations. Clearly there is a forgetful functor $\textsf{Equiv} \to \textsf{RSRel}$.

> Q: Does this functor have an adjoint? If so, is it given by any of the methods above?

> Q: What happens when $R$ is "just" a relation, i.e. not necessarily reflexive nor transitive? What is the adjoint to the forgetful functor $\textsf{Equiv} \to \textsf{Rel}$?

**Edit to add context**: I thought about this question when I was trying to work out what the [pushout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory)) in the category of sets should be (Exercise I.5.12. in [Algebra: Chapter 0](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-104)). I knew I had to quotient out by this reflexive and symmetric relation but I couldn't because it was not transitive! Eventually I came up with Method #1 which did the trick. I don't know a whole lot about adjoints (not enough to answer my own questions) but I'm curious about whether these (or other) methods are "natural" in any way.

Comment: Neither is preferred, depends on what you want to do with it. The first is the smallest equivalence relation containing $R,$ the second is the largest equivalence relation contained in $R.$ My guess is the first is way more common, but it really depends on why you are defining this.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews See my edit for added context. "Natural" is indeed subjective, which is why I phrased my questions in terms of functors and adjoints: so they have a definitive answer.

Comment: Neither is more natural - there is not definition of "more natural" in category, only "natural" and "not natural." Both are natural. One is, for your forgetful functor, a left adjoint, the other is a right adjoint.

Comment: But for any relation $R,$ whether reflexive and symmetric or not, can be grown to give something like the transitive closure (case (1)) and this is still an adjoint. But you might have to take a relation on a subset of $S$ for the general relation on $S$ for case (2).  Not sure. That's really about the forgetful functor from reflective symmetric to the category of sets with any relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relations on a set $X$ are just subsets of $X \times X$ and are ordered by inclusion, so it's simpler to work inside the poset of all such subsets for a given $X$. Given any relation $R$ we can consider the intersection of all equivalence relations containing it; intersections of equivalence relations are equivalence relations, so this is an equivalence relation, and it's the smallest equivalence relation containing $R$ which makes it the left adjoint of the inclusion of equivalence relations (on $X$) into all relations (on $X$). It's the equivalence relation *generated* by $R$.

It can be described more explicitly as follows: thinking of $R$ as describing a directed graph with vertex set $X$, we first convert each directed edge into an ordinary edge (which forces symmetry), then construct the equivalence relation given by sitting in the same path component (which forces reflexivity and transitivity). Alternatively we can phrase this in terms of [zigzags](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/zigzag).

This construction is the one relevant to constructing pushouts; to quotient by an arbitrary relation you quotient by the equivalence relation it generates.

The question now arises whether the inclusion of equivalence relations into all relations has a *right* adjoint. But it can't, because the union of equivalence relations is not an equivalence relation in general (it's not necessarily transitive), which means that the inclusion doesn't preserve colimits (joins). So I'm not sure how to generalize your second construction, but it's not the one relevant to constructing pushouts.